# How to cast SQL substring to decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a varchar column with various strings in table PriceTerm. so some of those I want to copy to another column.

So the source name and format is

```
[AdditionalDescription] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
```

and destinations

```
[PercentAddition] [decimal](28, 10) NOT NULL
```

I only want to cast those that contain % picked by SQL:

```
select AdditionalDescription from PriceTerm where AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%'
```

The output is like this.

```
AdditionalDescription
7,5 %
7,5%
7,5%
6 %
7,5%
6 %
3 %
....
```

That return 1696475 rows so it is a lot.

Obviously I have to remove % sign before I can cast it to a decimal value.

So I think it is several substeps.

1. Pick the rows to convert. Done by SQL above.
2. Remove  % so only number left in string.
3. Convert string to decimal and put it in column PercentAddition.

My question is how to implement step 2 and 3 ?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried those 2 SQL.

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(decimal(28,10), LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION], ',', '.'), '%', ''))))
FROM PriceTerm
WHERE AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%'

SELECT 
CAST(LTRIM(RTrim(REPLACE(REPLACE([ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION], ',', '.'), '%', ''))) AS Decimal(28,10))
FROM PriceTerm
WHERE AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%'
```

Both returned the same error.

Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

But the following works

SELECT 
CONVERT(decimal(28,10), LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE('5,8%', ',', '.'), '%', ''))))
FROM PriceTerm
WHERE AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%'

I try to list those that fulfill the condition and fail the conversion.

SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION], ',', '.'), '%', ''))) as PercentAddition
FROM PriceTerm
WHERE (AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%') AND ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([ADDITIONALDESCRIPTION], ',', '.'), '%', '')))) = 0

```
PercentAddition
express + 30
Express Transport +30
tillägg till faktura 115423. express +30
+ 30    (1.30*42.4sek=55.12sek)
+ 30    (1.30*42.4sek=55.12sek)
7.5*
7.5*
7..5
7..5
7.5.
7.5.
1.5  (minimi 4.20 €)
335 * 25 = 418.75
335 * 25= 418.75
10.6 &
vastaanottajan rahdinmaksu +4
Expressfrakt!!+30
```

Strange none of those contains % char.

**UPDATE 2:**
I try to filter away data that cannot be converted with this SQL

```
SELECT AdditionalDescription
FROM PriceTerm 
WHERE Created BETWEEN '2004' AND '2005' AND
AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%' AND
PercentAddition = 0 AND 
ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) = 0
```

The output:

```
AdditionalDescription

Snabbleverans + 30 %
Snabbleverans + 30 %
455 € + 4%
1,5 % (minimi 4,20 €)
1,5 % (minimi 4,20 €)
bränsle 7,5% ingår.
```

So those strings contain % but it is not possible to convert them to decimals. I want to skip those.

Counting valid numbers

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM PriceTerm 
WHERE Created BETWEEN '2004' AND '2005' AND
AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%' AND
PercentAddition = 0 AND 
ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) = 1
```

80051

Update the PercentAddition column

```
UPDATE PriceTerm 
SET PercentAddition = CONVERT(decimal(28,10), RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.'))))
WHERE Created BETWEEN '2004' AND '2005' AND
AdditionalDescription LIKE '%[%]%' AND
PercentAddition = 0
AND ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) = 1
```

Result

Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Anyone that have a hint of the reason ?

**UPDATE 3:**

So for example all those strange rows above that cannot be parsed is gonne be skiped.

```
+ 30    (1.30*42.4sek=55.12sek)
7.5*
7.5*
7..5
```

All above is converted to 0. Only those will be converted to decimal:

```
7,5%  -> 7.5
7,7 % -> 7.7
2.5   -> 2.5
```

I also tried to figure out how SQL CASE WHEN works. Could be something useful ?
Tried this:

```
UPDATE PriceTerm 
SET PercentAddition = 
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) = 1 THEN      
      CONVERT(decimal(28,10), RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.'))))
    ELSE 
      0.0
    END 
WHERE Created BETWEEN '2004' AND '2005' AND
AdditionalDescription LIKE '%[%]%' AND
PercentAddition = 0
AND ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) = 1
```

Output still Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
I even consider a stored procedure, but I have never used that before.
SQL Server 2012 have Try_Convert that would be really useful in this case. But I don't found a similar alternative for 2008 R2.

Comment: It looks like you don't have clean data. The column is just filled with all sorts of non-numeric characters. Maybe you will have to clean up the data.

Comment: Yes I agree. But How can I do that ? I have to filter those rows with dirty data first

Comment: You could go in and remove all non-numeric characters, but how will you handle data like `1,5 % (minimi 4,20 €)`? Is it `1,5%` or `4,20`? I think you need to look at the source of the data and see if you can clean it up at source.

Comment: I just want to ignore those rows that cannot be parsed. So for example '1,5 % (minimi 4,20 €)' this will be converted to 0.

Comment: See my updated answer, hope this will give you a start.

Answer (score 2):

Don't about how efficient this will be:

```
Select convert(decimal(28,10), rtrim(ltrim(replace(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.')))) As AdditionalDescription
from PriceTerm 
where AdditionalDescription like '%[%]%'
```

Explanation:

1. Remove % by replacing with space
2. Replace `,` with `.`
3. Remove any leading or trailing spaces.
4. Convert to `decimal(28, 10)`.

### Update:

As per additional info by OP.

```
Select 
convert(decimal(28,10),replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(AdditionalDescription)), ' ',''),',','.'),'%','')) AS PercentAddition
from test 
where replace(rtrim(ltrim(AdditionalDescription)), ' ','')
like '[0-9]%[,.]%[%0-9]'
and 
isnumeric(replace(replace(replace(rtrim(ltrim(AdditionalDescription)), ' ',''),',','.'),'%',''))=1
```

Explanation of `'[0-9]%[,.]%[%0-9]'`:

- `[0-9]` - We are interested only when the data starts with a number.
- `%` - After the number it may contain any character(s). We take care of non-numeric with `isnumeric` in `where` clause.
- `[,.]` - We have the data to have either `,` or `.`.
- `%` - After `[,.]` it may contain any character(s). We take care of non-numeric with `isnumeric` in `where` clause.
- `[%0-9]` - We want the data to end with either a digit or `%`.

**Note:** You will have to modify `'[0-9]%[,.]%[%0-9]'` as you find more bad characters.

**References:**

1. SQLFiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09a34/4
2. `LIKE` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It will be not the fastest way but try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription, '%', ''), ',', '.')) AS DecimalValue
FROM   PriceTerm
WHERE  AdditionalDescription LIKE '%[%]%'
```

This will replace % with empty string and commas with dots so 7,5% will look like 7.5 and then converted to a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the hardest part was validation if string is numeric. Builtin procedure IsNumeric returned false positive. Even if result was 1 CONVERT failed to cast the string to Decimal. The rescue came with Google and this [site](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html)

I use the stored procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isReallyNumeric  
(  
    @num VARCHAR(64)  
)  
RETURNS BIT  
BEGIN  
    IF LEFT(@num, 1) = '-'  
        SET @num = SUBSTRING(@num, 2, LEN(@num))  

    DECLARE @pos TINYINT  

    SET @pos = 1 + LEN(@num) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@num))  

    RETURN CASE  
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.-]%', @num) = 0  
        AND @num NOT IN ('.', '-', '+', '^') 
        AND LEN(@num)>0  
        AND @num NOT LIKE '%-%' 
        AND  
        (  
            ((@pos = LEN(@num)+1)  
            OR @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @num))  
        )  
    THEN  
        1  
    ELSE  
    0  
    END  
END  
GO
```

And used it like this:

```
UPDATE PriceTerm 
SET PercentAddition = CONVERT(decimal(28,10), RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.'), '&', '')))) 
WHERE AdditionalDescription LIKE '%[%]%' AND
dbo.isreallynumeric(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(AdditionalDescription,'%',''), ',','.'), '&', '')))) = 1 AND
PercentAddition = 0
```